# Finding which timezone names are at 8am

Tags: java, mysql, timezone

I have a user table in MySQL with a time zone column in `Europe/Paris` format. My goal is to find user for whom it's currently 8am from my Java app.

Just using `Europe/Paris` won't work because `Europe/Brussels` and `Europe/Amsterdam` have the same time zone and DST. So I would like to find all possible names for a specific time.

I also can't just use the GMT+1 offset as the daylight saving times will shift it during the summer and it will not switch for everyone on the same date.

I checked the TimeZone classes and couldn't find this.

Comment: What about converting all times into a single common timezone and then compare the output to whatever is Parisian 8am in the said timezone?

Comment: What is `a time zone column in Europe/Paris format`? I do not see that listed in the documentation for [MySQL data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque - MySQL Supports standard IANA/Olson time zone format.  `Europe/Paris` is an example.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

1. Get the current time in UTC.
2. For each time zone, convert to that zone's local time.
3. If the local time is the time you're looking for, then you have a match.
4. Query for all users with matching time zones.

A few points:

- You could do this either in MySQL, or in Java.  You didn't really say which you were looking for.
- You could optimize by limiting the time zones to test.  You'd have to ahead-of-time determine the standard and daylight offsets of each zone, then use this as a filter.
- When you check for "is it 8AM?" - you probably don't want to do an exact equality check, because it will only be 8:00:00.000 for one millisecond.  Instead you probably want to test against a range of values, such as `time >= 8:00 AND time < 9:00`

Comment: For the moment, I'm doing a `SELECT DISTINCT timezone FROM users`, compute the timezone for each and query the ones that have these time zones, so it's basically what you're suggesting. I'm rather trying to avoid this double query and just find out from a specific time, which timezones correspond to it (now).